# C# DataSafe - StackOverFlowExeption

Tags: c#, string

im learning C# and i try to build a "DataSafe".

I got a StackOverflowExeption and i dont find a Solution for my Problem. Is there a way that Visual Studio Shows me the Exeption in Detail?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Datensafe
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie eine beliebige Zeichenkette ein: ");
            String input = Console.ReadLine();
            Safe safe = new Safe(input);
            Console.WriteLine(safe.Treasure);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Safe
    {
        private string treasure;

        public Safe(String value)
        {
            Treasure = value;
        }

        public String Treasure
        {
            set { treasure = encrypt(value); }
            get { return decrypt(treasure); }
        }

        private string encrypt(string str)
        {
            byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        }

        private string decrypt(String encrypted)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Treasure);
            return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);

        }
    }
}
```

Could someone help me?

Here is the ErrorLog:

```
Process is terminated due to StackOverflowExeption

"Datensafe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Datensafe.vshost.exe): "C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert.
"Datensafe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Datensafe.vshost.exe): "C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert.
"Datensafe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Datensafe.vshost.exe): "C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert.
"Datensafe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Datensafe.vshost.exe): "C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert.
"Datensafe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Datensafe.vshost.exe): "C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert.
"Datensafe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Datensafe.vshost.exe): "C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert.
"Datensafe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Datensafe.vshost.exe): "C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert.
"Datensafe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Datensafe.vshost.exe): "U:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Datensafe\Datensafe\bin\Debug\Datensafe.vshost.exe" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert.
"Datensafe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Datensafe.vshost.exe): "C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert.
"Datensafe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Datensafe.vshost.exe): "C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert.
"Datensafe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Datensafe.vshost.exe): "C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert.
"Datensafe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Datensafe.vshost.exe): "C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert.
"Datensafe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Datensafe.vshost.exe): "C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert.
"Datensafe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Datensafe.vshost.exe): "C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert.
"Datensafe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Datensafe.vshost.exe): "C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_de_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll" geladen. Das Modul wurde ohne Symbole erstellt.
Der Thread 0x580 hat mit Code 259 (0x103) geendet.
Der Thread 0x2f4 hat mit Code 259 (0x103) geendet.
Der Thread 0xabc hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
Der Thread 0xa48 hat mit Code 259 (0x103) geendet.
"Datensafe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Datensafe.vshost.exe): "U:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Datensafe\Datensafe\bin\Debug\Datensafe.exe" geladen. Symbole wurden geladen.
Das Programm "[864] Datensafe.vshost.exe" wurde mit Code -2147023895 (0x800703e9) beendet.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line, this is causing recursion in accessing `Treasure`

```
 byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Treasure);
```

it should be

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
```

Comment: @kicki Glad it worked to you, please mark this as answer if it is the solution and works to you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Treasure` property:

```
private string decrypt(String encrypted)
{
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Treasure); // here
    return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
}
```

Thus you have infinite recursive call when you reading `Treasure` property value of your `Safe` class

```
Console.WriteLine(safe.Treasure);
```

Here you read property value, which tries to decrypt.. property value, which tries to decrypt.. property value etc

Just use `encrypted` param which you are passing to method:

```
private string decrypt(String encrypted)
{
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
    return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass in the `encrypted` method variable to the `FromBase64String` call:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
```

Now you are calling `decrypt` from the `Treasure` setter, and inside you use `Treasure` again.

---

**How you could have analyzed it yourself?**

To resolve a `StackOverflowException`, check the call stack. There must be repetition in the methods called. Take something in the middle from the call stack and see what is called over and over again. Check if the recursion is intended. If not, try to see where the repetition originates from (in this case the call to `Treasure` from your `decrypt` method).

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Treasure);
```

in the getter is wrong. You call decrypt in the getter and then you call the getter in decrypt.